# entity framework 4 unicode problem saving

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I am having problem using the Entity Framework 4 with MySQL connector 6.3.6. I have made MySQL dabase to utf8 - default collation to use the unicode on my website. The problem is that I can read the unicode to my website from the database by when I try to save the unicode string using entity framework 4 it put question marks on my database. I even set up the Unicode property from the Visual Studio designer but to no avail. Am I missing something or is there something you have to do to make entity framework write unicode to the database?

Answer (score 4):

Ok after alot of research it turns out that the MySQL connector 6.3.6 got a connection string parameter 'charset=utf8'. you need to add this to your connection string.

Answer (score 2):

> create connectionstring with 'charset=utf8' it on Web.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="con" connectionString="server=localhost;Uid=root;password=;database=webpro;charset=utf8 "  />    
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, somehow unicode configuration was disabled in context, here the solution is to set true value for .IsUnicode(true) Instead of .IsUnicode(false)

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Center>()
            .Property(e => e.CenterCode)
            .IsUnicode(true);
```

Let's enjoy this trick.