# How do I add an object with the entity framework when it has attribute to store data in utf-8

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

My application has an entity in DB that has two fields [id, word] where word is to store URDU words in it written in unicode. The fields have been created properly in DB such that on manually entering data it is being added properly but when I try to do the same thing via entity framework instead of proper words ???? appear .
    sr is the stream from which I am reading. and word is my entity.

```
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    String line = sr.ReadLine();
    word w = new word();
    w.name=line.Trim();
    context.words.AddObject(w);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

and the entity is as created in MYSQL 5.0

```
CREATE TABLE `word` (
  `wordid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(80) character set utf8 collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`wordid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15716 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: sr is the most probable culprit. For some reason it probably doesn't read strings correctly.

Comment: There are many reasons for this kind of behaviour. The one that is the most likely is that the final field is of type `varchar`. Try to make it `nvarchar`. And one vital question, what is your approach, do you create the database first or it is created automatically by EF? What version of EF are you using, 4 or 4.3+?

Comment: 'sr' cant be a culprit because when I am reading directly from file and trying to show that data in some listBox its viewed perfectly fine .

Comment: @Oybek   I have created DB first its in MYSQL 5.0 and the defination of my table as follows                                                                       
    CREATE TABLE `word` (
  `wordid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(80) character set utf8 collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`wordid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15716 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: As you were told, the char column just has to be nvarchar rather than varchar.

Comment: Well, here my level of skills end. I retagged to denote that MySql is involved also. You'll need to look at the gears of the MySql and the EF provider for it. May be there is something to do with it.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4836420/861716) apply to you?

Comment: @Wiktor When I am trying to enter data from the file using plain MySqlConnection the same Entity definition is working fine. But not with entity framework.  And I have tried with name to be NCHAR which is nvarchar in MYSQL but it still does not work.

Comment: @Gert Arnold Yes that is exactly the problem and thanks it works.

Comment: OK, great! Marked as duplicate of [entity framework 4 unicode problem saving](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836066/entity-framework-4-unicode-problem-saving). Duplicates are OK. Your question now serves as a signpost.

Comment: So, Hina, is this question answered? If so, please check it as answered. It shows up as not answered. Yet you said "it works"....

Comment: @RayKiddy yes it is answered but how do I do that. Doesnt to mark any question answered I have to have answers.